# ownCloud 9 Code Signing and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, code-signing, owncloud

I have a modified .htaccess where I added a RewriteCond.

Now I get on every page load:

> There were problems with the code integrity check. More information…

What is the right solution to prevent this error message? And of course, I don't want to use the original .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found a solution in the documentation, although core developpers say this shouldn't be done:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/issues/code_signing.html#errors

You could modify $OWNCLOUDHOME/core/signature.json file in order to update your .htaccess signature.

This should make owncloud think it has the right .htaccess file.

In order to do that:

1) run ./occ integrity:check-core

This will give you the expected signature and the actual signature for your core files.

2) edit core/signature.json and replace, on the .htaccess entry, the provided signature with your htaccess signature (given in step 1).

If, later, you need to file a bug report, owncloud developpers might ask you to restore the original .htaccess file and the original signature.json file, so make a backup. This feature is intended to mildly improve security and facilitate the developpers work.

Hope this will help you !

Edit Owncloud 9.1:

I've updated my own owncloud instance, and though I really do not recommand you to do that (use it at your own risks), you can disable code check in the config.php file.

Just add `'integrity.check.disabled' => true,`

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to fix without having to keep integrity check disabled:

1.) Open up the admin area where you can click **Rescan**, keep that window open (don't click rescan yet)

2.) Edit your `config/config.php` file, and add this line to it

```
'integrity.check.disabled' => true,
```

3.) Click on Rescan in browser window from step 1 (wait for it to complete)

4.) Change the line added to `config/config.php` from `true` to `false` (or remove the line)

Voila! Profit!

Looks like when you disable integrity check and click the rescan, it will re-generate the `signature.json` file, and after doing that, you can then re-enable integrity check

:)